# Qt - keyboard key press doing the same thing as mouse click

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning and messing around in Qt with Widget application and I made some QPushButtons that do some straight forward actions, but as you would expect only when you click them with mouse, how can you make it work that way, that a specific keyboard press event does that same work as clicking that button? I couldn't get much from online tutorials as I don't even know how to specify what am I looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use QShortcut or create derived class from QPushButton and re-implement QKeyPressEvent method